# Where to add "lang" parameter in a google script API for aftership.com last checkpoint request?

Tags: javascript, api, google-apps-script

```
  var trackingnumber = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange('G2').getValue();
  var header = {
    "aftership-api-key" : "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
    "Content-Type" : "application/json"
  };
  var payload = {
     "lang": "en"
  };
  var slug = "china-post";
  var tracking_number = trackingnumber;
  var options = {
    "method": "get",
    "headers": header,
    "payload": (payload)
  };
  var trackLastcheckpoint = UrlFetchApp.fetch("https://api.aftership.com/v4/last_checkpoint/"+slug+"/"+tracking_number, options);
```

Everything works fine without the payload, but when I add payload I got a return code 400

"Request failed for https://api.aftership.com/v4/last_checkpoint/china-post/XXXXXXXXXXXXX returned code 400. Truncated server response: {"meta":{"code":4001,"message":"Invalid JSON data. (001)","type":"BadRequest"},"data":{}} (use muteHttpExceptions option to examine full response) (line 123, file "Code")"

Where exactly to put the lang:en?

[Last Checkpoint API Doc](https://docs.aftership.com/api/4/last_checkpoint/get-last_checkpoint-slug-tracking_number)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about the following modifications?

In [the document of `getRequest(url, params)`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/url-fetch-app#getrequesturl-params), it is "Certain HTTP methods (e.g. GET) do not accept a payload." So it uses the optional parameter as the URL query parameter.

#### From :

```
var trackingnumber = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange('G2').getValue();
var header = {
  "aftership-api-key" : "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
  "Content-Type" : "application/json"
};
var payload = {
   "lang": "en"
};
var slug = "china-post";
var tracking_number = trackingnumber;
var options = {
  "method": "get",
  "headers": header,
  "payload": JSON.stringify(payload)
};
var trackLastcheckpoint = UrlFetchApp.fetch("https://api.aftership.com/v4/last_checkpoint/"+slug+"/"+tracking_number, options);
```

#### To :

```
var trackingnumber = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange('G2').getValue();
var header = {
  "aftership-api-key" : "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
  "Content-Type" : "application/json"
};
var slug = "china-post";
var tracking_number = trackingnumber;
var options = {
  "method": "get",
  "headers": header
};
var url = "https://api.aftership.com/v4/last_checkpoint/"+slug+"/"+tracking_number+"?lang=en";
var trackLastcheckpoint = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, options);
```

If this didn't work, I'm sorry.

Comment: @user3394010 Welcome. Thank you, too.